# Angular 5 Model to Object for Post Request

Tags: angular, post, undefined, angular5

I have the following problem. I would like to load data from a form and send it by post. I get the following error message: 'ERROR TypeError: Can not set property' barcode 'of undefined'

My contempt is that item.barcode is unknown. Although I create an object of type Item.

Here is my HTML code

```
<form class="item-form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput name="barcode" placeholder="Barcode" value="IN SH " [(ngModel)]="barcode">
  </mat-form-field>

  {{barcode}}
<br>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput name="itemName" placeholder="Item Name" [(ngModel)]="name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>

  <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput name="description" placeholder="Beschreibung" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="2"
                matAutosizeMaxRows="5" [(ngModel)]="description"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button color="green" (click)='onSubmit()'>Item speichern</button>
</form>
```

Here is my component TS code

```
public item: Item;
  public barcode: string;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;

  constructor(public itemFormService: ItemFormService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('onSubmit in Item Form Component');
    this.item.barcode = this.barcode;
    this.item.name = this.name;
    this.item.description = this.description;

    console.log(this.item);
    this.itemFormService.addItem(this.item);
  }
```

Here is my service TS code

```
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  addItem(item: any) {
    return this.http.post('', item, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where is `this.item` being set in your component?

Comment: In the first line
public item: Item;

export class Item {
  barcode: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

Comment: That is declaring a variable called `item`, but it's not actually instantiating it as far as I can see...

Comment: You mean something like item = new Item (); or? Now I'm still a noob. Can you give me a hint how this works? item = {} did not work either.

Comment: I've added an answer below to clarify, let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, although your `item` field has been declared, it has not been initialised. This means it has the default value of `undefined`.

You will first need to initialise it, using `this.item = new Item()`.

Alternately, you could do

```
item = {
    barcode: null,
    name: null,
    description: null
}
```

Please note that can cannot simply assign an empty object to `item`, because your `Item` type requires a barcode, name, and description.